# Expression must have pointer-to-object type at C

Tags: c

Here are the codes in order to send a string, get a response, and clears the buffer.

```
uint8_t usart6_tx_buffer[] = "AT+CPSI?\r\n";

while (usart6_tx_counter < sizeof(usart6_tx_buffer))
{
    while (usart_flag_get(USART6, USART_TDBE_FLAG) == RESET)
        ;
    usart_data_transmit(USART6, usart6_tx_buffer[usart6_tx_counter++]);
}
delay_sec(1);
usart6_tx_counter = 0x00;
printf("string: %s\r\n", usart6_rx_buffer);
for (usart6_rx_counter = 0; usart6_rx_counter < sizeof(usart6_rx_buffer); usart6_rx_counter++)
{
    usart6_rx_buffer[usart6_rx_counter] = 0;
}
usart6_rx_counter = 0;
```

This will send a "AT+CPSI?" string, receive data and prints it.

However, since i'm using this codes many times, i want to make that codes to a function like below.

```
void USART6_TxRx(uint8_t input)
{
    while (usart6_tx_counter < strlen(input))
    {
        while (usart_flag_get(USART6, USART_TDBE_FLAG) == RESET)
            ;
        usart_data_transmit(USART6, input[usart6_tx_counter++]);
    }
    delay_sec(1);
    usart6_tx_counter = 0x00;
    printf("string: %s\r\n", usart6_rx_buffer);
    for (usart6_rx_counter = 0; usart6_rx_counter < sizeof(usart6_rx_buffer); usart6_rx_counter++)
    {
        usart6_rx_buffer[usart6_rx_counter] = 0;
    }
    usart6_rx_counter = 0;
}
```

and want to use it like below.

```
uint8_t input;
uint8_t usart6_tx_buffer[] = "AT+CPSI?\r\n";
USART6_TxRx(*usart6_tx_buffer[]);
```

which i assume that should be work, but it keeps showing

```
expression must have pointer-to-object type usart_data_transmit(USART6, input[usart6_tx_counter++]);
```

whenever i build it.

are there anythings that i am missing?

Comment: @Support Ukraine sorry, there was a typo. it should be strlen(input)

Comment: As long as no answer has been posted, it's okay to edit the code in the question. So please do.... but remember: Once an answer has been posted such edits are not allowed.

Comment: `void USART6_TxRx(uint8_t input)` followed by `strlen(input)` makes no sense. I assume you want `void USART6_TxRx(char* input)` and call it like `USART6_TxRx(usart6_tx_buffer);`

Comment: @Popsicle Post definition of `usart6_tx_counter`.  Even better, post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint8_t usart6_tx_buffer[] = "AT+CPSI?\r\n";
uint8_t input[];

void USART6_TxRx(uint8_t *input, int size);
void USART6_TxRx(uint8_t *input, int size)
{
    while (usart6_tx_counter < size)
    {
        while (usart_flag_get(USART6, USART_TDBE_FLAG) == RESET)
            ;
        usart_data_transmit(USART6, input[usart6_tx_counter++]);
    }
    delay_sec(1);
    usart6_tx_counter = 0x00;
    printf("string: %s\r\n", usart6_rx_buffer);
    for (usart6_rx_counter = 0; usart6_rx_counter < sizeof(usart6_rx_buffer); usart6_rx_counter++)
    {
        usart6_rx_buffer[usart6_rx_counter] = 0;
    }
    usart6_rx_counter = 0;
}

void USART6_TxRx(usart6_tx_buffer, sizeof(usart6_tx_buffer));
```

using like this works.

Comment: `uint8_t input[];` is not valid C.

Answer (score 2):

`usart6_tx_counter++` You cannot use the `++` operators on an array. Furthermore, you most likely want that array to be `const`. You could so something like this instead:

```c
const uint8_t usart6_tx_buffer[] = "AT+CPSI?\r\n";

for(int i=0; i<sizeof(usart6_tx_buffer)-1; i++)  // -1 if not to send the null terminator
{
  while (usart_flag_get(USART6, USART_TDBE_FLAG) == RESET)
    ;
  usart_data_transmit(USART6, usart6_tx_buffer[i]);
}
```

Similarly, `USART6_TxRx(*usart6_tx_buffer[]);` is gibberish, pass on `USART6_TxRx(usart6_tx_buffer)` to a function like:
`void USART6_TxRx(const uint8_t* input)`